# MariaDB compare database schemas

Tags: database, mariadb

We are multiple devs working on a project with MariaDb backend.

We would like to have revisions for our db schema changes & put this in source control.

Is there a way/tool to compare MariaDb database schemas & script these changes?

I know DbForge offers support for MariaDb, but Im looking for a free alternative to this tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple. Dump schema with `mysqldump` tool(if I remember currectly, MariaDB has similar utils names) and save it in git/hg/svn.

```
mysqldump -u root -p --no-data dbname > schema.sql
```

It will create SQL query to create table, which will contain same format and every field will be on new line, so you can easily compare and make diffs in any tool to control versions.

There could be only one problem: commas. For example, if you have added new field, it will be added last, but previous will be changed - it will contain comma in the end at schema.sql, but it is common problem with any version-control tool, anyway you can find out more info by using diffs.

Answer (score 0):

to compare the schema of two MariaDB databases I'd suggest to use:

TiCodeX SQL Schema Compare (https://www.ticodex.com).

It also gives you the migration script to update the destination database in case there are differences.
It's a nice tools that runs in Windows, Linux and Mac and can compare the schema of MS-SQL, MySQL, MariaDB and PostgreSQL database. Easy to use and effective. It may help you.

It's worth to mention that is the only tool I've found that also works nicely on Linux and MacOS.

Comment: TiCodex is bancrupt: https://www.moneyhouse.ch/de/company/ticodex-sa-in-liquidazione-21108917591